# slow server response time IIS6 static content

Tags: asp.net, static, iis-6

We have IIs6 server. I tryed couple of our sites with googles Pagespeed insight tool. Everyting else seemed to be quite right exept that server respose time were too high.

after few test I made simpler static version of my orginal aps.net page. After that I removed most of pages content. And still server response time stays over o,6 seconds..

What could I do to serve static files more faster from IIS6 ?

I made couple of test to other sites on same server. Some of static content makes same response times, but there are also better ones even with dynamic pages. what causes different response times on different sites on same server?

How to find out what makes that slow response time with static content?

This is my test page:
http://www.keittiokoulu.fi/indextt.htm

and with tool:
https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/?url=www.keittiokoulu.fi%2Findextt.htm

response time now 0,66 seconds... I think it should be something like 0,1 seconds or so. i tryed same page over local network and crhomes debug tools. It says response time on server is 30ms.

Answer (score 0):

If you have other applications on IIS move your application to a new pool and clear and reset you server and check the resources available and used at your iis server.

Comment: yes.. i can do that. How do I that  I have check resources available and used?  IiS server has couple big sites on ten smaler ones. Bigger ones seems to be quite allright, but this smaller has slow response time, even with static content. is there a way i could debug my network connection too. Google glaims that it'sees real server response time but i doubt it.